# How to avoid Laravel PHP adding a prefix in a date with timezone

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code that fetches the date and time an order is made. I am doing this in Laravel PHP. I know how to echo the date in PHP using date().

The challenge here is however converting the timezone. The code below works and outputs the date correctly but it's instead adding a prefix `1` so that my date now looks something similar to
`1` `February 19, 2022 05:14 am`

The code is:

```
{date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi')} {$order_order_datetime|get_datetime:1}
```

And the challenge is to do away with the prefix. I can't get where the `1` is originating from.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` returns `true`, which is probably where the `1` is coming from. You should not be setting your timezone like that. Set your app timezone in the `config/app.php` file, or even better convert individual date instance timezones.

Comment: This looks less like an issue with setting and getting the date and more of an issue with the presentation on screen showing additional things from other sources. It's impossible to know with the information provided though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**config/app.php**

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

You can change your timezone in this config file in Laravel.

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you can see all timezones available.

[image]

However, if you are using simple PHP
You should follow :[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-date_default_timezone_set-function/#:%7E:text=The%20date_default_timezone_set()%20function%20is,not%20valid%2C%20or%20True%20otherwise.)

You can write this code to your index.php or entry php file. You do not need to echo `date_default_timezone_set`  this function. It says it changed the timezone and it returns 1. That's why you are seeing 1. You are echoing the result of a function. You do not need to echo that result. Just need to run.

Comment: Laravel is quite new to me. This returns a fatal error. ```'timezone' => 'Africa/Nairobi'```

Comment: It should not throw an error. I tried it on my local dev Laravel 9 and it worked just fine. You may have an error somewhere else. Can you share log file or the error output?

Comment: ```Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "themes\default\order.html" on line 32 "<li><i class="icon icon-calendar-date-2"></i> <strong>{$lang_created}</strong>{'timezone' => 'Africa/Nairobi'} {$order_order_datetime|get_datetime:1}</li>" - Unexpected " => ", expected one of: "}" <-- thrown in  ...\include\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 32```

Comment: Hey Dan, you are writing this code to wrong place. You should put this code to your config/app.php file. Inside you can see timezone key in the app.php array. You've put it in the view file. It is not a view related thing. It is configuration of your app. I added screenshot to my answer where you put it exactly.

Comment: There is no config folder. So I went ahead to create as shown but it didn't work. I think because the majority of the files are not written in Laravel PHP. This is the only file I have encountered with Laravel. Elsewhere the original code works, but it doesn't work in this particular file only. Again, maybe it's not working because the site is built on core PHP not laravel? Correct me.

Comment: You said " am doing this in Laravel PHP" so that's why I write according to Laravel. I think your site is not on Laravel it must be simple PHP. PHP is a language and Laravel is a framework there is no language called "Laravel PHP". I think the site is simple PHP. There should be main or bootstrap.php or index.php to your project. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-date_default_timezone_set-function/#:~:text=The%20date_default_timezone_set()%20function%20is,not%20valid%2C%20or%20True%20otherwise.

Comment: Yeah...how are you expecting anything Laravel related to work without the entire Laravel framework installed in your project?